# Percentage in StringFormat

Tags: c#, decimal, string-formatting

I have a technical problem with using percentage in `StringFormat` method.

The result of `String.Format("{0:P}", 0.8526)` is `85.26%`

but I think it should be `0.8526%`

Is it correct ? If yes , How can I get `0.8526%` ?

Comment: String.Format("{0}%", 0.8526)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```cs
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}%", 0.8526));
```

Answer (score 17):

Yes mathematically 0.8526 is equal to 85.26%. If you need to get 0.8526% then try this

```
String.Format("{0:P}", 0.8526/100)
```

Comment: I want to use DataFormatString in grid. how can I implement dividing there ?

Comment: In your case you do not even need to divide. if you need `0.8526` as `0.8526%` then why dont you add `%` to the number? `"0.8526%" = 0.8526.ToString() + "%"`. Does this help?

Comment: -1 Why divide and multiply by the same amount?  Just output {0}%

Comment: @ChrisGessler  Yes you are correct ! I missed that point. Cheers for -1.

Answer (score 2):

`String.Format` will multiply by 100 when you use % or :p [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
You should divide by 100 first if you want to get what you are looking for.

Comment: -1 Why divide and multiply by the same amount? Just output {0}%

Comment: @Chris because String.Format will take into account the current culture's rules for formatting a percent value while {0}% is hard-coding to the US-EN standard.

Comment: It's kind of like hard-coding to a specific culture, but not really. The double will be formatted implicitly using the G format specifier. Ignoring the percent symbol entirely, the G format specifier formats numbers differently than P, primarily in how many decimal places are shown by default. You should just read about G and P on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 2):

A percentage is considered from 0-100% and the related floating pointer number from 0.0-1.0 as it is a ratio between two numbers.